# Using the EditText method & what it can do

Tags: java, android

i'm kinda new to programming with java and everything and was seeing if anyone could help me with this.  I'm trying to make it so that it can save a file and then be able to open it up but i cant try and run the app yet because of the red lines.  Can anyone help me with the correct way for the code to go? Thanks

```
'public class Documents extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.documents);
    EditText txtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
}
public void saveClicked(View v) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out =
        new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));
        out.write(EditText.gettext.toString());
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "The contents are saved in the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
private final static String STORETEXT="storetext.txt";

public void readFileInEditor(){
    try{
        InputStream in=openFileInput(STORETEXT);
        if (in !=null){
            InputStreamReader tmp=new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;
            StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
            while ((str=reader.readLine()) !=null){
                buf.append(str+"n");
            }
           in.close();
            EditText.setText(buf.toString());
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // that's OK, we probably haven't created it yet
    }catch (Throwable t){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}'
```

}

Comment: Try debugging or printing your variables to see at what point in the code does it stop doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: He is trying to use his app and save data to a text file, and also use the app to read from the text file

Comment: The red lines in Eclipse that show compile errors? If you hover the mouse over one, it will tell you the error message. (I assume it's the same in Android Studio/IntelliJ, since this is a common feature in IDEs)

Comment: "the red lines" is not specific enough. Those are likely compile errors. YOu need to tell us what they are.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Since the application won't compile, how can he debug it?

Comment: He never mentioned it won't compile. He said sth about 'red lines', but I don't think it's really accurate. And if it doesn't compile, he could at least tell us where the error occurs.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski `but i cant try and run the app yet because of the red lines`

Comment: He doesn't need to run, just tell us what lines generate errors, and if it does compile, the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

`Edittext` is not a method, it is a class.

`EditText.setText(buf.toString());`

This is wrong.  Read about classes and objects (instances of classes).  You haven't told us what the problem is but I guess you are trying to set the text on `txtview`.

Second problem, since you declare `txtView` in `onCreate()` it is only visible in `onCreate()`.  Try moving it to a class field.

```
public class Documents extends Activity {

    EditText txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.documents);
        txtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
    }
```

Then in `readFileInEditor`(which **is** a method)

```
txtView.setText(buf.toString());
```

Since you are learning, you will quickly find your next problem.  One question per problem please.

Comment: okay i fixed that but then in this line of code               'out.write(EditText.gettext.toString());'     the gettext is turning red, how do i fix that?

Comment: 2 things.  Please one question per post and, `EditText.getText()` does not exist.  You really need to learn the difference between a class and an object.  `getText()` is a method of an object (instance) of `EditText`.  It is not a static method of `EditText`.  You can use `txtView.getText()` if that is what you want to do. Really, you will not be successful building an app until you understand these basic concepts.  Since this answer solved the initial question, please accept it and start a new question for this problem.